# Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem (Folland)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

When reading this theorem in Folland's real analysis (p.90), I meet one questions here:

[image]

1. From above $\lambda \bot \mu,\ \ \rho \ll \mu$. Can I say "$\rho \bot \lambda$" or "$\rho \bot \lambda$" a.e.? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Source : Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, chapter 6 p.120)*

**Definition :** If there is a measurable set $A$ such that $\mu(E) = \mu(A \cap E)$ for every measurable set $E$ we say that $\mu$ is *concentrated* on $A$.

**Answer :** $\rho \perp \lambda$.

**Proof :** Since $\lambda \perp \mu$ there is a set $A$ with $\mu(A) = 0$ on which $\lambda$ is concentrated. Since $\rho \ll \mu$ then $\rho(E) = 0$ for every $E \subseteq A$. So $\rho$ is concentrated on the complement of $A$.